# What is the recommended waiting time between requestRandomWords and fulfillRandomWords calls in Chainlink VRF V2?

Tags: solidity, oracles, chainlink, vrf

Recently, Chainlink published their VRF v2. The new VRF uses subscription management app. There is a delay between the requestRandomWords and fulfillRandomWords function.

**On the Goerli test net, average time is around 300 seconds.** Therefore, I set a timeout of 300 seconds between request and fulfill function calls.

**Is there a way to find this pending time programmatically?**

In the documentation, they mention

"You can see a list of pending requests for your subscription ID in the Subscription Manager"

I wasn't able to find an API that would give me a pending time for my subscription id in chainlink docs.

**What is the recommended waiting approach between requestRandomWords and FulfillRandomWords function calls?**

Comment: I am also wondering the same thing. Trying to call requestRandomWords in fulfillRandomWords.

Comment: Currently, I am trying to estimate it using num of confirmation I provide and see the average block finality time and use that as my base value to wait between requestRandomWords and fulfillRandomWords functions. This way I can get the correct state changes implemented by fulfillRandomWords. However, I can't think of anything better. Perhaps, a smart contract provided by chainlink that tells us estimated waiting time for given subscriber id would be a better option

Comment: Using event listeners could be another way to solve this problem. Example. https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/test/staging/RandomNumberConsumerV2_int_test.js

Answer (score 0):

[Shubham Sharma](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/96407/shubham-sharma)

The waiting time depends on the `requestConfirmations` parameter.

- requestConfirmations: The number of block confirmations the oracle node will wait to respond.
- The longer the node waits, the more secure the random value is.
- It must be greater than the minimumRequestBlockConfirmations limit on the coordinator contract.
- The minimum and maximum confirmations for your network can be found [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/supported-networks/#configurations).

Like you said in comments, using event listeners is excellent if you would like to know when your smart contract receive the numbers = when the function `fulfillRandomWords` was called. You can create an event to be called inside the function, per example.